# Apparent inconsistency during type casting in C++ (and C)

Tags: c++, casting

By any chance can anyone explain the output here? I have been trying to understand why type casting a literal is having a result different from type casting a variable in this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double intermediate;
    intermediate = -1.0;
    cout << "intermediate = " << intermediate << endl;
    cout << "uint64_t(intermediate) = " << uint64_t(intermediate) << endl;
    cout << "uint64_t((double)(-1)) = " << uint64_t((double)(-1)) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is:

```
intermediate = -1                                                                                                                                   
uint64_t(intermediate) = 18446744073709551615                                                                                                       
uint64_t((double)(-1)) = 0
```

Comment: Can you specify your OS, compiler, and the arguments you passed to the compiler and/or linker to create your executable?

Comment: I was using Cygwin-GCC on Windows 10, no arguments passed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're performing an out-of-range conversion from a floating point type to an integer type.

Since the double value `-1.0` cannot fit in a `uint64_t`, this is considered an out-of-range conversion.  Such a conversion invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  This means, among other things, that the two attempts at conversion need not produce the same results.

Note that this differs from signed integer to unsigned integer conversion which is well defined in all cases.

This is dictated by 7.10p1 of the [C++17 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf):

> A prvalue of a floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of an
>   integer type. The conversion truncates;that is, the fractional part is
>   discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be
>   represented in the destination type.

Section 6.3.1.4p1 of the [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) has similar language:

> When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer
>   type other than `_Bool`, the  fractional  part  is  discarded  (i.e., 
>   the  value  is  truncated  toward  zero).  If  the  value  of the
>   integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior
>   is undefined. <sup>61)</sup>
>
> ...
>
> 61)   The  remaindering  operation  performed  when  a  value  of 
>   integer  type  is  converted  to  unsigned  type need  not  be 
>   performed  when  a  value  of  real  floating  type  is  converted  to
>   unsigned  type.  Thus,  the range of portable real floating values is
>   (−1,Utype_MAX+1)

To get a consistent result, you would first need to cast to a signed integer type, then an unsigned type.

```
cout << "uint64_t(intermediate) = " << 
        static_cast<uint64_t>(static_cast<int>(intermediate)) << endl;
```

For C:

```
printf("uint64_t(intermediate) = %llu\n", (uint64_t)(int)intermediate);
```